# Facebook open graph not being read correctly

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I have a facebook like button and facebook meta tags on a page. I changed the og:description tag but dont see the change when I click on the Like button on my page. It is picking up the old description. In order to force facebook to scrape my page , I go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug and enter the URL again. It shows the updated decription there. But not when I am liking it. Is there any parameter that I need to pass to force a scrape seperately ?

Help appreciated !

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Some Title" />
<meta property="og:type" content="activity" />
<meta property="og:url" content="Some url" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.cruises.com/images/ship_ext/norwegian_34/34_444_d_Jewel_150.jpg" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Cruises.com" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Hey, I found this wonderful cruise to Alaska !" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="682339085" />
```

These are the tags that I am using.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook will lock in certain values after X # of likes. Since cruises.com has 784 current likes (See https://graph.facebook.com/http://cruises.com), then I'm sure that those values are locked down.

Comment: Two things 1) AFAIK the title and the type tag get locked down after 50 likes but the other tags can be changed any number of times, read this here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/ in the editing tags section. 2) Does facebook count the number of likes based on the site(http://www.cruises.com) or the page Id - meaning a particular page hosted on cruises.com? we need to get this done and out soon and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Also if I look at the graph for that particular page https://graph.facebook.com/http://cruises.com/testFacebook.html shows only one share.

Comment: Yeah, when I go to that page itself it show 0.  So maybe the stats are not instant stats, but maybe counted at some later time.  Could be caused by db sync issues.  Or maybe the values are stored in a cache for performance.